# Opção template não mostra em wordpress custom page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou criando uma nova aba igual a de "page" porém, separado, ficando como a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que eu criei um template personalizado, ou seja eu mesmo criei meu tema, na aba "pages" aparece a opção template

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que nessa aba "locations" que eu criei não aparece a opção de template, alguém sabe como colocar?

Segue o código do register.

```
function locations_register(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Locations','post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Locations', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add new location', 'location'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new location'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit location'),
        'new_item' => __('New location'),
        'view_item' => __('View location'),
        'search_items' => __('Search location'),
        'not_found' => __('Nothing Result'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing result on the bin'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'taxonomies'=> array('features'),
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor','page-attributes') 
        );

    register_post_type('location', $args);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu não me engano, não é permitido em qualquer tipo de custom post, isso não foi implementado por que as postagens personalizadas podem ser denominadas usando a hierarquia de WP padrão.

Por exemplo, você está criando um tipo de publicação chamado location, você pode criar um modelo chamado single-location.php, ele vai aplicar o modelo apenas às postagens personalizadas desse tipo.. isso se aplica a tudo praticamente..

Outro exemplo, archive-location.php se aplica à página de arquivo.

Você pode até adicionar page-{post-id}.php para criar um modelo para uma página específica... e por ai vai.